# Add "alt" Attribute to GD Star Rating <img> Tags

Tags: php, custom-field, plugin-gd-star-rating

I have try over a week to validate 4 images that are retrieved by a code with [GD Star Rating plugin](http://www.dev4press.com/plugins/gd-star-rating/)

This is the code i have:

```
wp_gdsr_render_rating_results(array('template_id' => 49, 'rows' => 4, 'select' => 'post', 'hide_empty' => false, 'min_votes' => 0, 'min_count' => 0, 'excerpt_words' => 0, 'image_from' => 'custom', 'image_custom' => 'img', 'image_resize_x' => 72, 'image_resize_y' => 80,  ));
```

So the output look's like this:

[image]

I dig on google and I modify the code to get me the poster by a custom field.

This I add to retrieve the picture from a custom field.

```
foreach ($all_rows as $row) {
    if ($widget["image_from"] == "content") {
        $row->image = gdFunctionsGDSR::get_image_from_text($row->post_content);
    } else if ($widget["image_from"] == "custom") {


    $post_custom_id = get_post_meta($row->post_id, $widget["image_custom"], true);

        $row->image = get_bloginfo('url')."/scripts/timthumb.php?src=".get_bloginfo('url')."/wp-content/uploads/".get_post_meta($post_custom_id,"_wp_attached_file",true)."&amp;h=70&amp;w=55&amp;zc=1";
    }
     else if ($widget["image_from"] == "trailer") {
        $post_custom_id = get_post_meta($row->post_id, $widget["image_trailer"], true);// getVideoId is a custom function
        $row->image ="http://img.youtube.com/vi/".$post_custom_id ."/0.jpg" ;

    } else $row->image = "";

    $row->image = apply_filters('gdsr_widget_image_url_prepare', $row->image, $widget, $row);

    if ($row->image != "" && intval($widget["image_resize_x"]) > 0 && intval($widget["image_resize_y"]) > 0) {
        $row->image = GDSRRenderT2::prepare_image($row->image, $widget["image_resize_x"], $widget["image_resize_y"]);
    }
```

> Note:
>
> This is the original code line 139

http://code.google.com/p/gd-star-rating/source/browse/trunk/code/t2/render.php?r=1041

The code I added is :

```
$row->image = get_bloginfo('url')."/scripts/timthumb.php?src=".get_bloginfo('url')."/wp-content/uploads/".get_post_meta($post_custom_id,"_wp_attached_file",true)."&amp;h=70&amp;w=55&amp;zc=1";
                    }
```

So the question how can I add to the images the alt attribute to display in the html page.

The error i get in http://validator.w3.org is

```
Line 580, Column 195: An img element must have an alt attribute, except under certain conditions. For details, consult guidance on providing text alternatives for images.

…tent/uploads/Battleship_1333017069_2012.jpg&amp;h=70&amp;w=55&amp;zc=1"/></div>
```

Comment: Can you show how you are displaying image markup?

Comment: i'm not understand wath you are refering... Vinod..

Comment: nobody knows how to corect this?

Answer (score 1):

Add the attribute to each line of code that creates an img tag. In your text editor, search for lines that contain the string `"<img"`.

Lines 241 and 273:

```
$row->item_trend_rating = sprintf('<img class="trend" src="%s" style="%s" width="%s" height="%s"></img>', $gdsr->e, $image_bg, $set_rating->size, $set_rating->size);
```

Becomes:

```
$row->item_trend_rating = sprintf('<img class="trend" src="%s" style="%s" width="%s" height="%s" alt="%s"></img>', $gdsr->e, $image_bg, $set_rating->size, $set_rating->size, 'ALT TEXT HERE' );
```

Change ALT TEXT HERE to the text you want to use here.

Line 503:

```
$rater_stars = '<img src="'.STARRATING_URL.sprintf("gfx.php?type=thumbs&value=%s", $score).'" />';
```

Becomes:

```
$rater_stars = '<img src="'.STARRATING_URL.sprintf("gfx.php?type=thumbs&value=%s", $score) . '" alt="' . $score . '" />';
```

Lines 506 and 511:

```
$rater_stars = '<img src="'.STARRATING_URL.sprintf("gfx.php?value=%s", $rating).'" />';
```

Becomes:

```
$rater_stars = '<img src="'.STARRATING_URL.sprintf("gfx.php?value=%s", $rating) . '" alt="' . $rating . '" />';
```

I used $rating as the alt text because it looks like a string. Feel free to change it.

Comment: sorry but is not working.. no alt atribute is show in html

Comment: Did you check for typos (using WordPress debugging)?